# change directory of tmp file for sqlite3

Tags: linux, indexing, sqlite, temporary-files

So I am trying to create an index on a large sqlite table (~ 1 billion rows)

As part of the index creation process, sqlite has to create the whole index B-tree structure and store it on my main drive (SSD) before committing it to the DB even though the DB itself is stored on a different drive (1 TB disk).

The problem is that I have limited space on my SSD and the index creation fails because of insufficient tmp space on my SSD.

So the question is, how do I make sqlite store the tmp files on a directory other than where sqlite is installed ?

Comment: [The docs](https://sqlite.org/tempfiles.html) say that "On unix-like systems, directories are searched in the following order:

1. The directory set by PRAGMA temp_store_directory or by the sqlite3_temp_directory global variable
2. The SQLITE_TMPDIR environment variable
3. The TMPDIR environment variable
4. /var/tmp
5. /usr/tmp
6. /tmp
7. The current working directory (".")"

Comment: Great. Thank you !!